# Make a radio button a link within an HTML email in gmail

Tags: javascript, html, gmail, html-email

I am trying to build a simple form that will be sent in an HTML email, and will primarily be opened in gmail.  Since gmail strips out the Javascript, I'm wondering how I can make each of the radio buttons act as a clickable link.  Normally, I've been using `onclick="window.location='www.link.com';"` on the radio button , but this no longer works once sent through gmail as an HTML email.  Any suggestions?

Edit: What I'm looking for is the ability for a user to click the radio button corresponding to their answer on a poll and the clicking of the radio button takes them to a separate page, outside of gmail.  Essentially each individual radio button needs to be a link, or a way to add a submit button that goes to a different link dependent on which radio button has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No email clients support Javascript or any kind of special click events outside of defaults.**

If your goal is to take "them to a separate page, outside of gmail", a basic `<a href>` should be able to do that. If you want to give it the *appearance* of a radio button, you can make an image and link the image:

```
<a href="">
    <img src="radio-button.png" alt="Image the looks like a radio button">
    Text Label
</a>
```

This would mimic selected a radio button and submitting a `<form>` as you would on the web. Pretty basic, but should achieve what you describe above.

Answer (score 0):

Email programs don't typically like `PHP` or `Javascript` so what you need to do is thing *Internet 2004* and make it all that way. Campaign Monitor makes a great too for HTML email buttons that can be found [here](https://buttons.cm/).